# Event Registration Bug

Tags: civievent

On our registration page, we ask that to register, you enter the number of registrations being purchased. When you enter 1, 2, 3, etc., it multiplies that by the registration fee of $315. Which is GREAT!

The problem comes when someone enters 0.00- it allows that person to register for the event for FREE. Help!

Can you help?

Sherry Jennings

[image: Correct]

[image: Incorrect]

Answer (score 2):

You could set up the price field to be a select drop down an make the options 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. With the corresponding price for each quantity. This is not open ended you would have to setup quantities based on how many options you want to provide people.

Another option is to use the register multiple participants option in the online registration setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, KilakwaBT! If we do that, we cannot use discount codes. Any other ideas? Discount codes are important to us.

Comment: Discount codes should work with either option above. For the select number of tickets option the code would have to be a percentage in order to apply correctly. With the register multiple participants option the code will apply to the pricing for all participants.

Comment: We wouldn't want the discount applied to more than one registration. :(